# Is there a good and secure way to implement a QR code that acts as a User ID for an end user to scan and check the validity of?

Tags: performance, security, authentication, authorization, qr-code

Think like upon registration, the user gets a personal QR code. This code acts as a identifier for the user (think key fob). Would you need to update the QR each day or what would make it secure without putting a lot of workload onto the server ( i.e generating new QR code for the user every call).

Or is the solution with the person scanning the QR code, having some sort of algorithm to decipher a hash of some sort..?

The security risk, in this context, is another person getting hold of someone’s personal QR code userid.

Looking for any inputs on the matter! Thank you.

Comment: Also, get a password/pin from user so that you have now two factor authentication?

Answer (score 0):

No, like a printed-text name badge, there is no almost no inherent security in an unchanging QR code. THE QR code can be photographed and reproduced.

Comment: Is there a way to limit the QR codes use within the application?